# How to design a bulletproof method of relating a string to base string?

Tags: java, algorithm

My service communicates with a server that manages accounts.

- Each **Account** has a cap on the number of **operations** performed per month.
- I want to circumvent this cap by creating new accounts that are related via a scheme.

This is how it should work:

1. User creates an account "*denzel*" via **MyService**.
2. **MyService** in turn, proxies the account creation to **3rdPartyServer**
3. User "*denzel*" checks his credit and **MyService** returns $45 (default cap per user account).
4. User "*denzel*" buys additional $45 via **MyService**. **MyService** surreptitiously creates (in the background) account *A* in **3rdPartyServer** but manages the relation between "*denzel*" & "*A*".
5. User "*denzel*" checks his credit and **MyService** returns $90

A dumbass way to manage the relation is to append a count to the original userid.
e.g. "*denzel1*", "*denzel2*" etc.. This does not work we don't want to prevent other users from choosing *denzel1*" or others in the series for that matter.

Has anyone faced this problem and has a solution to share ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do the accounts created automatically at **3rdPartyServer** need to be based on the original user's login? You might as well randomly generate them and then manage them seamlessly "in house" so that user doesn't even need to know about them. As [George said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866937/how-to-design-a-bulletproof-method-of-relating-a-string-to-base-string/866948#866948), use a Reference table that allows you to cross reference a user of your system with all of their generated aliases.

Comment: Good point. I might as well just generate a GUID everytime and use that for the 3rdPartyServer. Bingo!

Comment: yep, that's the ticket. The tricky bit now is how you make it appear seamless. Especially if it is possible that a user can end up with $1 in each of two accounts and try to perform a $2 action!

Answer (score 3):

Use a [reference table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_table) to manage the mappings between real users and generated users.  That way you can check if you have already generated an account with a given name.